# End of lines problem in emacs when editing markdown texts via It's All Text

Tags: emacs, markdown

I want to edit markdown source in emacs using the It's All Text plugin for firefox.

In markdown you have to add two spaces to the line-end to get a new line. Suppose there is such a newline in a markdown source. If I open this in emacs via It's All Text, change something else and save it then the two spaces at the end of the line dissapear which is very annoying. So is there a way to configure emacs not to touch such spaces at line ends in this case?

Comment: I'm far from sure it is an emacs problem and not an "It's All Text" one.  Do you reproduce with a simple text file? If yes, does customizing `require-final-newline` solve your problem?

Comment: *It's All Text* (an *excellent!* FF plugin) works fine in my `emacs`.. Yes there is a way to do what you want. It is more a case of do you only want the *keep-whitespace* behaviour for those particular files, or for all files..  I have my emacs set to keep whitespace... I can't recall off-hand the setting... You will need a hook to *some process* to be buffer specific.. and that's just a bit out of my scope, but the blanket setting is probably(?) available from the menu in... (not sure though, I don't use the menu_..

Comment: *Keeping trailing whitespace* is `emacs` default behaviour, so perhaps you can test it with no extras loaded. Do this by telling `It's All Text` to launch `emacs` via restrictive options.  The command is  `emacs -Q`, but `It's All Text` doesn't like the arg, so put the command into a bash script, eg. `ita-emacs`, and tell `It's All Text` to run `ita-emacs`, then test it.  (`emacs -Q` is equivalent to `-q --no-site-file --no-splash`)

Comment: @Peter.O Thanks, that helped. After seeing that it worked with `emacs -Q` I figured out, that I have the following line in my .emacs file: `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)` Commenting out this line solved the problem. Perhaps you could convert your comment into an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a follow-on to my comment, the following procedure is often helpful in tracking down what is causing what.. (trial and error testing, really...)...

Keeping trailing whitespace is `emacs` default behaviour, so perhaps you can test it with no extras loaded. Do this by telling *It's All Text* to launch `emacs` via restrictive options. The command is `emacs -Q`, but *It's All Text* doesn't like the arg, so put the command into a bash script, eg. `ita-emacs`, and tell It's All Text to run `ita-emacs`, then test it. (`emacs -Q` is equivalent to `-q --no-site-file --no-splash`) ...

If the spaces are not deleted , then you at least know that it is an `emacs` issue in the loaded extras..

---

PS: for anyone who may not have already read all the comments (above), *student* tested as mentioned, and found the following line in his *.emacs* file: `(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'delete-trailing-whitespace)` ... The culprit! :)

Answer (score -3):

As a way to circumvent this problem, instead of using two spaces for new-line I use the escape character `\`. It works, at least, with Pandoc.

Example:

```
This is an example\
of using \\ as\
a new-line marker.
```

I found this not-exactly-solution here:
https://gist.github.com/shaunlebron/746476e6e7a4d698b373#gistcomment-2271765

Comment: This is a good work-around, but is not an Answer to "a way to configure emacs not to touch such spaces at line ends in this case"

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you for clarifying my mistake.